# Grok Filter for Confluence Logs

Tags: regex, logstash, logstash-grok

I am trying to write a Grok expression to parse Confluence logs and I am partially successful.

My Current Grok pattern is :

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:conflog_timestamp} %{LOGLEVEL:conflog_severity} \[%{APPNAME:conflog_ModuleName}\] \[%{DATA:conflog_classname}\] (?<conflog_message>(.|\r|\n)*)

APPNAME [a-zA-Z0-9\.\@\-\+_%\:]+
```

And I am able to parse the below log line :
Log line 1:

**2020-06-14 10:44:01,575 INFO [Caesium-1-1] [directory.ldap.cache.AbstractCacheRefresher] synchroniseAllGroupAttributes finished group attribute sync with 0 failures in [ 2030ms ]**

However I do have other log lines such as :
Log line 2:

**2020-06-15 09:24:32,068 WARN [https-jsse-nio2-8443-exec-13] [atlassian.confluence.pages.DefaultAttachmentManager] getAttachmentData Could not find data for attachment:
-- referer: https://confluence.jira.com/index.action | url: /download/attachments/393217/global.logo | traceId: 2a0bfc77cad7c107 | userName: abcd**

and Log Line 3 :

**2020-06-12 01:19:03,034 WARN [https-jsse-nio2-8443-exec-6] [atlassian.seraph.auth.DefaultAuthenticator] login login : 'ABC' tried to login but they do not have USE permission or weren't found. Deleting remember me cookie.
-- referer: https://confluence.jira.com/login.action?os_destination=%2Findex.action&permissionViolation=true | url: /dologin.action | traceId: 8744d267e1e6fcc9**

Here the params "userName" , "referer", "url" and "traceId" **may or maynot be present in the Log line**.
I can write concrete grok expressions for each of these. Instead can we handle all these in the same grok expression ?

In shorts - Match all log lines..

- If log line has "referer" param store it in a variable. If not, proceed to match rest of the params.
- If log line has "url" param store it, if not try to match rest of the params.
- Repeat for 'traceId' and 'userName'

Thank you..

Comment: Hi, I have already captured timestamp, severity, ModuleName, classname and conflog_message as shown in my initial Grok expression. The referer, url , traceId and username are currently captured as a single text "conflog_message". I would like to split it...

Comment: Does [**this**](https://regex101.com/r/t5wP4t/1) help?In order to make your capturing clear; I used named capturing groups.

Comment: Please do let me know if it helped or you need something else.

Comment: The Regex seems fine, however I am struggling to convert it to Grok..

%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:conflog_timestamp} %{LOGLEVEL:conflog_severity} \[%{APPNAME:conflog_ModuleName}\] \[%{DATA:conflog_classname}\] %{GREEDYDATA:conflog_message} -- ((?:\breferer\b: (?<referer>.*?)|\burl\b: (?<url>.*?)|\btraceId\b: (?<traceId>.*?)|\buserName\b: (?<userName>.*?))(?: \||$)|[a-zA-Z0-9.@+_%:-]+) gives me only referer...

Comment: Another version, gives me all the fields, however it's not dynamic (meaning if referer is not there it fails to match) 

%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:conflog_timestamp} %{LOGLEVEL:conflog_severity} \[%{APPNAME:conflog_ModuleName}\] \[%{DATA:conflog_classname}\] %{GREEDYDATA:conflog_message} -- ((?:\breferer\b: (?<referer>.*?))(?:\burl\b: (?<url>.*?))(?:\btraceId\b: (?<traceId>.*?))(?:\buserName\b: (?<userName>.*?))(?: \||$)|[a-zA-Z0-9.@+_%:-]+)

FYI I am trying in https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/

Comment: You are right about the first part. 
"you need to refer using the named group in order to get all the values". I am not sure how exactly to do it ? Is there any way I can share a screen snip with you ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216953/discussion-between-mandy8055-and-majo).